# WPF MVVM retrieve datagrid selected rows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid with checkbox implemented on it using this code which I found on the internet.

```
<my:DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type my:DataGridRow}}}" />
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</my:DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

But, how can I get the selected rows? I am using WPF MVVM.

Comment: Please can you folks add a comment to question when you guys are downvoting. Then, they will know WHY their questions are downvoted. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

since you're using the MVVM pattern you can declare a ViewMode like this:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Prototype> Items { ... }
    public Prototype SelectedItem SelectedItem { ... }
}
```

After, in your datagrid, you can declare binding in this way:

```
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"... />
```

In your code you can use the "SelectedItem" property to get current selected datagrid row.
Else if you mean "checked" rows, you can query your observable collection:

```
var selectedRows = ViewModel.Items.Where(i => i.IsSelected);
```